# Logstash - Read JSON files

Tags: json, logging, logstash, filebeat, logstash-file

I am trying to configure Logstash which should read all json files which are located in specific directory. 
JSON files update every time by python script and I need to read all files from scratch every time (not just checking the last lines).

I have tested two variants of configs:

1 config:

```
input {
  file {
  path => "/tmp/*.json"
  start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

output{
  stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}
```

2 config:

```
input {
  file {
      path => "/tmp/*.json"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      ignore_older => 0
  }
}

output{
  stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Result in both cases:

1. Logstash can`t detect the changes when python updates the files (File timestamp is changing every time)
2. Even if I change something inside of the file logstash detects it only first time and print full file but after that it can`t detect changes anymore.

**Final result:**
At the end Logstash just need to get all files (new files should be detected automatically) in specific directory, read the content and push it somewhere. Can you please help to do it?

Comment: is your input file name contain timestamp ?

Comment: No, it has only simple name

Comment: it will read one file only at one time to prevent duplicacy and if filename name is same it does'nt read file and it will ignore that file it's better to use append timestamp after your prefix in log filename.